# How to detect an error in item creation on the client side (App Maker)

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker

I am creating an app to store schedules and I do not want two schedules with the same date. To combat this I added this code (javascript) to the `onBeforeCreate()` and `onBeforeSave()` events.

```js
var query = app.models.DataSource.newQuery(); // New query

query.filters.date._equals = record.date; //Search for a record that has the same 

if (query.run().length) {
  throw new Error("There is already a schedule on that date"); // Throw an error
}
```

This works great to prevent the duplicate entries, but how would I go about detecting this on the client side and reporting it to the user?

Its probably a quick fix but any input would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to modify the datasource field to be unique. 
You'll need to go to **ModelName > FieldName > Advanced**:

[image]

Then, when creating the item on the client side, let's say, for example, using a button widget which its datasource is set in **create mode**, then on the **onClick** event handler, use the following:

```
widget.datasource.createItem({
  success: function(record){
    console.log(record._key);
  },
  failure: function(error){
    var err = error.toString();
    if(err.indexOf("Duplicate entry") > -1){
      alert("There is already a schedule on that date");
    } else {
      alert(error.toString());
    }
  }    
});
```

For more information, I recommend you to consult the [**official documentation**](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/client#types_of_callbacks).